# C# Bearing and distance calculation (using Vincenty's formula) results in NaN?

Tags: c#, formula, wgs84

following this article to calculate the point from a lat and long with a bearing and distance when run results in NaN?

article below :

A method is given for calculating the destination point for ellipsoid earth models using Vincenty's formula:

Convert the starting point latitude 'lat1' (in the range -90 to 90) to radians.
lat1 = lat1 * PI/180
Convert the starting point longitude 'lon1' (in the range -180 to 180) to radians.
lon1 = lon1 * PI/180
Convert the bearing 'brg' (in the range 0 to 360) to radians.
brg = brg * PI/180
Ellipsoid earth models

Note: the variable 'flat' below represents the earth's polar flattening used in various ellipsoid models. For the commonly used WGS-84, let flat = 298.257223563.

Given the distance s in meters, the semi-major axis 'a' in meters, the semi-minor axis 'b' in meters and the polar flattening 'flat'.
Calculate the destination point useing Vincenty's formula. Shortened variable names are used.

```
f = 1/flat
sb=sin(brg)
cb=cos(brg)
tu1=(1-f)*tan(lat1)
cu1=1/sqrt((1+tu1*tu1))
su1=tu1*cu1
s2=atan2(tu1, cb)
sa = cu1*sb
csa=1-sa*sa
us=csa*(a*a - b*b)/(b*b)
A=1+us/16384*(4096+us*(-768+us*(320-175*us)))
B = us/1024*(256+us*(-128+us*(74-47*us)))
s1=s/(b*A)
s1p = 2*PI
```

Loop through the following while condition is true.

```
while (abs(s1-s1p) > 1e-12)
cs1m=cos(2*s2+s1)
ss1=sin(s1)
cs1=cos(s1)
ds1=B*ss1*(cs1m+B/4*(cs1*(-1+2*cs1m*cs1m)- B/6*cs1m*(-3+4*ss1*ss1)*(-3+4*cs1m*cs1m)))
s1p=s1
s1=s/(b*A)+ds1
```

Continue calculation after the loop.

```
t=su1*ss1-cu1*cs1*cb
lat2=atan2(su1*cs1+cu1*ss1*cb, (1-f)*sqrt(sa*sa + t*t))
l2=atan2(ss1*sb, cu1*cs1-su1*ss1*cb)
c=f/16*csa*(4+f*(4-3*csa))
l=l2-(1-c)*f*sa* (s1+c*ss1*(cs1m+c*cs1*(-1+2*cs1m*cs1m)))
d=atan2(sa, -t)
finalBrg=d+2*PI
backBrg=d+PI
lon2 = lon1+l;
Convert lat2, lon2, finalBrg and backBrg to degrees
lat2 = lat2 * 180/PI
lon2 = lon2 * 180/PI
finalBrg = finalBrg * 180/PI
backBrg = backBrg * 180/PI
```

If lon2 is outside the range -180 to 180, add or subtract 360 to bring it back into that range.
If finalBrg or backBrg is outside the range 0 to 360, add or subtract 360 to bring them back into that range.
Note: the variables 'a', 'b' and 'flat' above have the following relationships:

```
b = a - (a/flat)
flat = a / (a - b)
```

so porting this formula to c# i ended up with:

```
        double Latitude = 50.390202;
        double Longitude = -3.9204310000000078;
        double Bearing = 225;

        double lat1 = Latitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        double lon1 = Longitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        double brg = Bearing * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        double s = 1000;

        double a = 6378137.0;
        double b = 6356752.314245;

        double f = 1 / 298.257223563;
        double sb = Math.Sin(brg);
        double cb = Math.Cos(brg);
        double tu1 = (1-f) * Math.Tan(lat1);
        double cu1 = 1 / Math.Sqrt((1+tu1*tu1));
        double su1 = tu1 * cu1;
        double s2 = Math.Atan2(tu1, cb);
        double sa = cu1 * sb;
        double csa = 1 - sa * sa;
        double us = csa * (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);
        double A = 1 + us / 16384 * (4096 + us * (- 768 + us * (320 - 175 * us)));
        double B = us / 1024 * (256 + us * (-128 + us * (74 - 47 * us)));
        double s1 = s / (b * A);
        double s1p = 2 * Math.PI;

        while (Math.Abs(s1-s1p) > 1e-12)
        {
            cs1m = Math.Cos(2 * s2 + s1);
            ss1 = Math.Sin(s1);
            cs1 = Math.Cos(s1);
            double ds1 = B * ss1 * (cs1m + B / 4 * (cs1 * (-1 + 2 * cs1m * cs1m) - B / 6 * cs1m * (-3 + 4 * ss1 * ss1) * (-3 + 4 * cs1m * cs1m)));
            s1p = s1;
            s1 = s / (b * A) + ds1;
        }

        double t = su1 * ss1 - cu1 * cs1 * cb;
        double lat2 = Math.Atan2(su1 * cs1 + cu1 * ss1 * cb, (1 - f) * Math.Sqrt(sa * sa + t * t));
        double l2 = Math.Atan2(ss1 * sb, cu1 * cs1 - su1 * ss1 * cb);
        double c = f / 16 * csa * (4 + f * (4 - 3 * csa));
        double l = l2 - (1 - c) * f * sa * (s1 + c * ss1 * (cs1m + c * cs1 * (-1 + 2 * cs1m * cs1m)));
        double d = Math.Atan2(sa, -t);
        double finalBrg = d + 2 * Math.PI;
        double backBrg = d + Math.PI;
        double lon2 = lon1 + l;

        lat2 = lat2 * 180 / Math.PI;
        lon2 = lon2 * 180/ Math.PI;
        finalBrg = finalBrg * 180/ Math.PI;
        backBrg = backBrg * 180 / Math.PI;

        if (lon2 < -180)
        {
            lon2 = lon2 + 360;
        }
        if (lon2 > 180)
        {
            lon2 = lon2 - 360;
        }

        if (finalBrg < 0)
        {
            finalBrg = finalBrg + 360;
        }
        if (finalBrg > 360)
        {
            finalBrg = finalBrg - 360;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lat2, lon2);
```

but when run result in NaN for both lat2 and lon2?

expected result should be:

Latitude: 50°23′02″N   50.38384479
Longitude: 3°55′49″W   -3.93037298
Final bearing: 224°59′32″   224.99234101
Back bearing: 44°59′32″   44.99234101

does c# calc do something different of have i made a mistake in there that i cant see :(

Thanks

Comment: Have you stepped through your code?  You are experiencing NaN issues way before the final output.

Comment: Debug your application and check the values at each step. In general it's a very bad idea to reuse a variable to hold different calculations as you do here with `lat2` and `lon2` - you can't determine what went wrong just by looking the variable values. Also break the code into separate functions that you can test independently. It's impossible to make sense of all this, much less *test* it.

Comment: Step through your code carefully & check your values. After 2nd time through the loop you will find that ds1 is already "Infinity".

Comment: If you describe three different steps in your question, you should write *at least* three different functions - at least one different function to implement each step.

Comment: i was only trying to port over the formula from here[link](http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/calculation.html) but guessing not that easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) b = (1-f)a

so your 10th line of code should be :

```
   double b = a * (1 - 1 / flat);
```

NOTE - I haven't checked for any other problems, but it does give values that are not NaN.

Comment: Thanks from your wiki link i just amended a and b  to :-  `double a = 6378137.0; double b = 6356752.314245;` as im using WGS84 and works a treat. Thanks